# Accessing the request object from within a class based view? Needed to determine if the request is coming from a mobile device

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have the following CBV:

```
class Index(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'index_app/index.html'
```

As well as a function that could take the a request object and return whether its coming from a mobile device or not:

```
def mobileBrowser(request):

mobile_browser = False
ua = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].lower()[0:4]

if (ua in mobile_uas):
    mobile_browser = True
else:
    for hint in mobile_ua_hints:
        if request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].find(hint) > 0:
            mobile_browser = True

return mobile_browser
```

I want to be able to use this to do something like the following in my CBV:

```
class Index(TemplateView):
if mobileBrowser(request):
    template_name = 'index_app/mobile/index.html'
else:
    template_name = 'index_app/index.html'
```

This isn't possible, as a CBV doesn't seem to have access to the request object. Is there any way that this object can be accessed in this situation?

I know it would be possible to create a standard view instead, but later on I would like to continue using CBVs like CreateView and whatnot, which will just land me in the same situation again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the request using `self.request`. The best place for this logic is in `get_template_names`

```
def get_template_names(self):
    if mobileBrowser(self.request):
        template_name = 'index_app/mobile/index.html'
    else:
        template_name = 'index_app/index.html'
    return template_name
```